# Algorithm to minimize sum of diagonals for triangulation of convex polygon?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic, geometry, triangulation, convex-polygon

Define the cost of a triangulation as the sum of the lengths of the diagonals that have been added. Given a convex polygon, what is the cost of its cheapest triangulation? If we consider the polygon as a set of n coordinates: v_1=x_1,y_1,...,v_n=x_n,y_n and the solution must have n-3 diagonals (not overlapping because it's triangulation)

I have been trying to get the reccurence of this Dynamic programming problem but I can't seem to find a good one. I do not really recognize suboptimal structure to find the recurrence. Anyone could give me a hand on this?

Comment: Can you explain what this has to do with C++?

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to find a solution using c++, but I am new to this, it's just that if anyone wanted to give a try for me it's more familiar c++

Comment: This is a question about an algorithm. The answer to the question will be the same whether it's coded in C++, Java, Python, Perl, PHP, Basic, or any other Turing-complete programming language. After you figure out what the algorithm is, attempt to code the solution in C++, and are having a problem of some kind, then this will become a C++ question. But not before then.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik sorry just deleted it, thanks for the info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The simplest method** would be to iterate over every point, get the distance between the previous and the next point, and recurse with the polygon without the current point; e.g. for a pentagon *abcde* that would be:

- distance *eb* + recurse with quadrangle *bcde*
- distance *ac* + recurse with quadrangle *cdea*
- distance *bd* + recurse with quadrangle *deab*
- distance *ce* + recurse with quadrangle *eabc*
- distance *da* + recurse with quadrangle *abcd*

[image: recursive triangulation of pentagon]

In order not to calculate the same solutions more than once, you should discard any solutions where points that have already been checked do not have a diagonal arriving in them; e.g. when recursing with quadrangle *deab* in step 3, the solution with a diagonal *eb* is a duplicate, because solutions that use triangle *abe* were already checked in the first step. 
Making no duplicate calculations at all may be complicated with this method.

**Another method** would be to choose a point *(indicated in red in the illustration below)*, and then enumerate every solution as a number of digits whose sum is *n - 2*, where n is the number of points. The solution where every diagonal goes through the selected point would be solution 11111. Then, you run through every combination that sums to *n - 2*: 11111, 1112, 1121, 113, 1211, 122, 131, 14, 2111, 212, 221, 23, 311, 32, 41 and 5. A number greater than 1 means you combine 2 or more segments, and add the diagonal from its first to last point. When the number is greater than 2, this diagonal borders a left-over polygon *(indicated in pink)*, which you recurse with.

The animation shows the iterations and recursions the algorithm goes through for a 7-point polygon, up until the point where it recurses with a 6-point polygon.

[image: recursive triangulation of septagon]

Both these methods offer possibilities for memoization and tabulation, but it won't be straightforward. A pentagon starting at point b isn't necessarily *bcdef* once you've started recursing; it might well be *bdfhj*. So retrieving stored intermediate results may get a bit complicated.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking about the first method too but I'm having a hard time with the retrieval of the results as you say. I'll update with my solution if I achieve one